# Scrapy: LinkExtractor not working

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl Erowid and gather data about experiences. I am trying to get from the general information about a drug to the actual experience itself.

However the LinkExtractor doesn't seem to be working.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from Erowid.items import ErowidItem


class ExperiencesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["www.erowid.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.erowid.org/experiences/subs/exp_aPVP.shtml']
    rules = [ 
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =('/experiences/exp.php?ID=[0-9]+')),     callback = 'parse_item', follow = True)

    ]
    def parse_item(self, response):
        [other code]
```

From https://www.erowid.org/experiences/subs/exp_aPVP.shtml, I am trying to reach the experiences which have an href of

```
/experiences/exp.php?ID=  (some digits)
```

I can't find the proper code after ID and I have already tried already a variety of different regex including

```
\d+ and [0-9]+
```

Is the error caused by an incorrect regex expression? If yes then what would be the correct regex expression? If no then why is this error occurring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the expression that works for me:

```
/experiences/exp\.php\?ID=\d+$
```

And here is how the `rules` look:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/experiences/exp\.php\?ID=\d+$'),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True)
]
```